# Not able to delete the cookies on logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, logout

//Interface--Injecting into controller

```
  public interface IContext
{
    HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
    HttpResponseBase Response { get; }
}
```

//Implementation

```
  public class Context : IContext
{
    public HttpRequestBase Request { get { return new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request); } }
    public HttpResponseBase Response { get { return new HttpResponseWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Response); } }
}
```

//Setting Cookie on login.
    SetCookie(_context, login);

```
public void SetCookie(IContext context, Login login)
{
        var loginDetails = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(login);
        var cokie = new HttpCookie("login", login);
        context.Response.Cookies.Add(cokie);
}
```

//Trying to Logout.

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        foreach (var key in _context.Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Response.Cookies.Remove(key); //this didn't work

                //tried this even this is not working
                var login = new Login {Identity = "", LogIn = false};
                _login.SetCookie(_context, login);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        _context.Response.Cookies.Clear(); //this didn't work either

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
```

On Login Index when I check the current login  cookie value it always has the value of the logged in user is just not getting set to null or empty.
I suspect there is something wrong in the Implementation of the IContext. Should there be a setter  on it? Not sure..

Also Tried:

```
        var cokie = context.Request.Cookies["login"];
        cokie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
        cokie.Value = null;
        context.Response.Cookies.Add(cokie);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code if you are using forms authentication. It will clear all the required cookies

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
```

Alternatively you can use

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Clear();
```

or

```
YourCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
```

For more information please visit

[MSDN Cookie Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If to log user in you use

```
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)
```

you can try

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

instead of

```
_context.Response.Cookies.Clear();
```